# Sentence Parsing & Parentheses matching with python

Tags: python-2.7

I need to turn some sentences into arrays to render parse trees.

At beginning, I have sentences that already tagged.

**Tagged Sentence:**

> (S (NP (PRP You)) (VP (VBP are) (ADJP (JJ riight))) (. .))

Then I numbered the sentences.

**When numbered, It looks like this:**

> (1-S (2-NP (3-PRP 4-You)) (5-VP (6-VBP 7-are) (8-ADJP (9-JJ 10-right))) (11-. 12-.))

However, I need to turn it into an Array. By using Regular expression, It's easy to turn the numbered sentence into something likes this to represent an array:

```
var DataArray = [
{ key: 1, text: "S"}, 
{ key: 2, text: "NP",  parent: "?" }, 
{ key: 3, text: "PRP",  parent: "?" }, 
{ key: 4, text: "You",  parent: "?" },  
{ key: 5, text: "VP",  parent: "?" },  
{ key: 6, text: "VBP",  parent: "?" },    
{ key: 7, text: "are",  parent: "?" },    
{ key: 8, text: "ADJP",  parent: "?" },  
{ key: 9, text: "JJ",  parent: "?" }, 
{ key: 10, text: "right",  parent: "?" }, 
{ key: 11, text: ".",  parent: "?" }, 
{ key: 12, text: ".",  parent: "?" } ]
```

The tricky part is how to dynamically find each key's parent key number. I guess it has something to do with parentheses matching.

**The Array I wanted looks like this:**

```
var DataArray = [
{ key: 1, text: "S"},   
{ key: 2, text: "NP",  parent: "1" }, 
{ key: 3, text: "PRP",  parent: "2" }, 
{ key: 4, text: "You",  parent: "3" }, 
{ key: 5, text: "VP",  parent: "1" },  
{ key: 6, text: "VBP",  parent: "5" }, 
{ key: 7, text: "are",  parent: "6" }, 
{ key: 8, text: "ADJP",  parent: "5" },   
{ key: 9, text: "JJ",  parent: "8" },   
{ key: 10, text: "right",  parent: "9" },     
{ key: 11, text: ".",  parent: "1" },     
{ key: 12, text: ".",  parent: "11" } ]
```

It's basically the text version of a syntax tree: With each child key matched to it's parent key.

[The visual represention tation of the above data array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqrXp.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You could write code yourself its very easy

1) Use any loop (while or for)

2) Iterate over string

3) Set an openBrackets count to 0 opnBr=0 and initialize array

4) Reading the characters at the respective positions, and increment opnBr when you see an opening bracket and decrement it when you see a closing bracket and continue the loop for next iteration.

5)if its character (apart from bracket) check if that key(opnBr) is already present then update else add parent = opnBr-1 and key = opnBr;

Thats it.

Happy Coding :)